# Using Query String Parameter to Select Column in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, querystringparameter

I am trying to use asp:QueryStringParameter to change witch SQL table column I want to get. But when I try, I just get the Query String Parameter as every row of a new column.

Here is what I have so far.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="getContact" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="
        SELECT 
            [fName], 
            [lName], 
            @c as contact    
        FROM 
            RidesMaster 
        WHERE 
            [userID] = @ID">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="c" QueryStringField="c" Type="String" />
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: You will have to build the query string dynamically in the code behind or, easier, select all the possible columns and change the visibility in the control.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a CASE statement so long as your dynamic columns are of the same type or could be cast to the same type:

```
SELECT 
  [fName], 
  [lName],
  CASE @c
    WHEN 'column1' THEN [column1]
    WHEN 'column2' THEN [column2]
    WHEN 'column3' THEN [column3]
    ELSE 'column4'
    END as contact    
FROM 
  RidesMaster 
WHERE 
  [userID] = @ID
```